# CURSOR is not displaying data/result set

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, jasper-reports

I've tried everything I could and i still can't get my `cursor` to display data. here is my code:

```
DECLARE 

CURSOR SL_Cur IS
    select *
    from (
        select
            cdav.bank_id,
            ent.bank_desc Bank_Description,
            cdav.sol_id,
            sol.sol_desc SOL_Description,
            cdav.gl_sub_head_code GLSH_Code,
            decode(cdav.gl_sub_head_code,
                '10301',1,
                '10403',2, '60403',2, '10501',2, '60501',2, '10502',2, 
                '10503',2, '10504',2, '10505',2, '10507',2, '10509',2, 
                '60509',2, '10511',2, '10518',2, '60518',2, '10523',2, 
                '60523',2, '10551',2, '10552',2, '10553',2, '10554',2, 
                '10555',2, '10557',2, '10559',2, '10561',2, '10568',2, 
                '10573',2,
                '12336',3, '62336',3, '10401',3, '60402',3, 4 ) GLSH_SET ,
            gsh.gl_sub_head_desc GLSH_Name,
            case
                when (cast(substr(cdav.gl_sub_head_code,0,1) as int) >= 1
                    and cast(substr(cdav.gl_sub_head_code,0,1) as int) <= 5)
                then 'R'
                when cast(substr(cdav.gl_sub_head_code,0,1) as int) = 0
                    or (cast(substr(cdav.gl_sub_head_code,0,1) as int) >= 6
                    and cast(substr(cdav.gl_sub_head_code,0,1) as int) <= 9)
                then 'F'
            end book_type,
            gam.foracid account_number,
            gam.acct_name,
            cdav.tran_crncy_code Tran_Currency,
            cdav.value_date,
            cdav.tran_date Transaction_Date,
            cdav.gl_date,
            cdav.tran_particular,
            rank() over(partition by gam.foracid order by eab.eod_date desc) eod_date_rank,
            eab.eod_date,
            case when
                (select tran_date_bal from tbaadm.eab
                    where eab.eod_date = (select max(eab.eod_date) from tbaadm.eab
                        where cdav.acid = eab.acid and eab.eod_date < '28-MAY-2013')
                    and cdav.acid = eab.acid
                    and cdav.bank_id = eab.bank_id) is not null
                then (select tran_date_bal from tbaadm.eab
                    where eab.eod_date = (select max(eab.eod_date) from tbaadm.eab
                        where cdav.acid = eab.acid and eab.eod_date < '28-MAY-2013')
                    and cdav.acid = eab.acid
                    and cdav.bank_id = eab.bank_id)
                else 0
            end beg_tran_date_bal,
            (select tran_date_bal from tbaadm.eab eab
                where eod_date = (select max(eab.eod_date) from tbaadm.eab eab
                    where cdav.acid = eab.acid and eab.eod_date <= '28-MAY-2013')
                and cdav.acid = eab.acid
                and cdav.bank_id = eab.bank_id) end_tran_date_bal,
            ott.ref_num OAP_Ref_No,
            trim(cdav.tran_id) Transaction_ID,
            --cdav.dth_init_sol_id Initiating_SOL_ID,
            'PCC_Code',
            cdav.tran_rmks Tran_Remarks,
            case
                when (cdav.part_tran_type = 'D')
                then (cdav.tran_amt)
            end dr_amount,
            case
                when (cdav.part_tran_type = 'C')
                then (cdav.tran_amt)
            end cr_amount

        from tbaadm.ctd_dtd_acli_view cdav
            left outer join tbaadm.gam
                on cdav.bank_id = gam.bank_id and cdav.acid = gam.acid
            left outer join tbaadm.gsh
                on gam.bank_id = gsh.bank_id and gam.sol_id = gsh.sol_id
                and gam.gl_sub_head_code = gsh.gl_sub_head_code
                and gam.acct_crncy_code = gsh.crncy_code
            left outer join tbaadm.sol
                on cdav.bank_id = sol.bank_id and cdav.sol_id = sol.sol_id
            left outer join tbaadm.eab
                on gam.bank_id = eab.bank_id and gam.acid = eab.acid
            left outer join tbaadm.cnc
                on gam.bank_id = cnc.bank_id and gam.acct_crncy_code = cnc.crncy_code
            left outer join crmuser.end ent
                on cdav.bank_id = ent.bank_id
            left outer join tbaadm.gct
                on cdav.bank_id = gct.bank_id
            left outer join tbaadm.ott
                on cdav.tran_id = ott.tran_id and cdav.tran_date = ott.tran_date
                and cdav.part_tran_srl_num = ott.part_tran_srl_num
                and cdav.bank_id = ott.bank_id and cdav.acid = ott.acid

        where
            gam.acct_ownership = 'O'
            and cdav.bank_id = 'CBC01'
            and cdav.gl_date = '28-MAY-2013'
            and (gam.gl_sub_head_code in ('10301','10403','60403',
                '10501','60501','10502','10503','10504','10505',
                '10507','10509','60509','10511','10518','60518',
                '10523','60523','10551','10552','10553','10554',
                '10555','10557','10559','10561','10568','10573',
                '12336','62336','10401','60402')

                or gam.acct_classification_flg in ('I','E')
                )
            and trim(cdav.del_flg) in ('N', null)
            and trim(gam.del_flg) in ('N', null)
            and trim(gsh.del_flg) in ('N', null)
            and trim(sol.del_flg) in ('N', null)
            and trim(cnc.del_flg) in ('N', null)
            and trim(gct.del_flg) in ('N', null)
    )

    where
        eod_date_rank = 1
        and GLSH_SET = 1

    order by
        bank_id,
        sol_id,
        tran_currency,
        glsh_code,
        book_type desc,
        account_number,
        transaction_date;

  in_sl_rec SL_Cur%ROWTYPE;
```

BEGIN

```
open SL_Cur;

LOOP
    FETCH SL_Cur INTO in_sl_rec;


    exit when SL_Cur%notfound;
END LOOP;

close SL_Cur;
```

END;

At first, I just need to make the `CURSOR` display the result set that I want to see. Next, I want to make the cursor into a sort of `FOR LOOP`, because there would be input parameters involved when executing the code in `iReport`, mainly a date range.

Answer (score 1):

Cursors don't just "display" when you execute them - you have to write a little code to do that. Try adding the following lines in your loop after the `exit when SL_Cur%notfound;` and just before the `END LOOP;`

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('BANK_ID=' || in_sl_rec.BANK_ID ||
                     'Bank_Description=' || in_sl_rec.Bank_Description ||
                     'sol_id=' || in_sl_rec.sol_id ||
                     'SOL_Description=' || in_sl_rec.SOL_Description);
```

You can add more fields as you need to.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I've added the lines you suggested, it does nothing. I swear, the query inside the `cursor` is working it returns the result set that I want to see. It's when I added the `cursor` and other bits that the code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @JamesP This answer works for sure. If you see no results then you have other problems like your cursor returns nothing or you have suppressed `dbms_output` output in your client.

Comment: @user272735 how do I know if `dbms_output` is suppressed? and if it is, how do I "un-suppress" it [for lack of a better term]?

Comment: @JamesP if you're using something like SQL*Plus, pass `set serveroutput on` or exec `dbms_output.enable`

Comment: @Sathya well it's working now, I can see the output in the `DBMS Output`. what I need now, is how to display the records in a data grid/ as a result set.

Comment: dbms_output.put_line just   "prints". if you want to display the result in GRID then I would suggest to declare a SYS_REFCURSOR as OUT parameter .